# Laravel inertia app not loading assets for first time

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

In my Laravel app I have 3 different logins `Admin, Staff, User`. After the login is successful each module has different assets to be loaded. I am changing the `blade file` for each different user using `rootView function`  in handleInertia middleware like this

```
public function rootView(Request $request){
        if(request()->is('admin/*')){
            return 'app';
        }else if(request()->is('staff/*')){
            return 'app';
        }else {
            return 'FrontEnd.app';
        }
    }
```

app.blade.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/admin/css/app.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/admin/css/custom-style.css') }}">
```

frontend.app

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js">
    </script>
```

Right now after the login is done the first time the assets will not load. After refreshing the page the assets get loaded. I do not understand what is wrong in my code.

Comment: how you manage assets in your project?
like I assume you have managed like `public/Admin/<your assets>` and same for the other roles, isn't it?

Comment: yes the assets are in different folders I will update my question with assets links

Comment: much better, thanks

Comment: updated thank you

Comment: check when you are logged in what you get in asset URL in inspect element. then reload the page and check? hope you will get an idea.

Comment: if I reload the page it is working

Comment: I meant here, when the page first time is loaded, check what is the assets URL is?

Comment: when first time its loaded the assets are not changing. The old assets are present the new one is not updating